# Hiding a column value before exporting to xls

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-gridcontrol

I have a gridview, `gridViewOrders`, with master-detail relationship. I am hiding default values for the column `OrderedDate` in `gridViewOrders_CustomUnboundColumnData` event as follows

```
if((DateTime)e.Value == DEFAULT_DATE)
{
     e.Value = null;
}
```

When I try to export the same grid (using `gridViewOrders.ExportToXls(fileName)`) to an Xls; these hidden values are shown in the excel as exported excel file which something not intended. I want the detail row not to display the value if it `= DEFAULT_DATE` (`DEFAULT_DATE = 01/01/2000`).

### MainView

```
Id  Name  OrderedDate
 1   K_23 
 2   J_11  12/03/2019
 3   K_4   15/02/2020
 4   P_3
```

### Exported to XLS

```
 Id  Name  OrderedDate
 1   K_23  01/01/2000
 2   J_11  12/03/2019
 3   K_4   15/02/2020
 4   P_3   01/01/2000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please try setting [`TextExportMode`](http://docs.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpress.XtraPrinting.TextExportOptionsBase.TextExportMode) to `Text`

For example:

```
yourGrid.ExportToXls(yourFilePath,new DevExpress.XtraPrinting.XlsExportOptions()
{
                TextExportMode = DevExpress.XtraPrinting.TextExportMode.Text
});
```